# How to track how much time user spent on my android application?

Tags: android

I want to track how much time user spent on my android application. Can I get time in Hours and it tracks automatically, when user's active on application.

**Note:** Application is not on Google Play.

Comment: In onResume, take the time.  In onPause take the time.  Subtract the two.  That's the time spent.  Keep track of the cumulative amount in a file somewhere.

Comment: Using [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/)

Comment: Maybe you can inherit from application and calculate the time there

Comment: onResume and onpause would not solve the issue on application as whole. @GabeSechan

Comment: @Onik Application is not on Google Play

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja It would if you did it in every activity

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to get application use time:

```
long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long end = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long total = end-start;
```

Later, you can use this method:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().setCustomVar()
```

Comment: Calendar will count time for one instance or total time application has been played. @gbesler

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Analytics.
It will show the device and the time.

Comment: Application is not on Google Play

Comment: Get the current system time, and store it when the application starts. Then in stop/destroy, get the current time and subtract with the previous time stored. you will get the time

Comment: what if there are multiple pages then oncreate, onresume, onpause, so much of work but will leak time as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can signup for Flurry. It is a free service and includes many tracking features.
http://www.flurry.com/

Stats on Country,time,retention,Devices etc.

A general idea on how it is done is `onStart` of any Activity you store a Date and in  `onDestroy` you get current Date and calculate the difference between the two.

This way you can detect the time spent on the Activity.

Comment: suggest some features that we can have as our own not any service is needed.

Comment: can you give more detail. what type of features ?

Comment: feature for which question is asked @Kabira

Comment: yup. all that code can be done for you with Flurry and it is much more advisable to be honest. It tracks average time spent on app. Without service user would have to have  his own server where he/she sends stats. Much more effort

Comment: we have our own server where we are sending our stats that's why this application is not online on Google Play.

Comment: Okay, so you get the idea ? .. simply send the time calculated to the server on next launch. You would have to maintain a log of the session  times. doing a network request in onDestroy might not finish always

Comment: That's point you are missing, we are asking you how to calculate that time without missing through out the application? We know when to send stats but we need stats first that to accurate stats.

Comment: can you come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow