# How to measure how much time all users spend in the app with Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

We have successfully implemented GA but one thing is still a riddle.

What I'm looking for is how much time (sum) users spend using the app. I need simple report with time period on the X axis and sum of minutes on the Y axis. This can help to measure user engagement in minutes during the time.

Did anyone figure how to implement it on Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Get it the start time and store it somewhere when the app starts.

```
long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Also get the end time after the user logged in to the app.

```
long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Get the time spent by the user.

```
long timeSpent = endTime - startTime;
```

Then use the `'GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().setCustomVar()'` method to set this data inside your track event.

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537345/how-to-track-how-much-time-user-spent-on-my-android-application)